# Optimal way to replace substrings given a table

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

Whats the best/most optimal way in replacing substrings in a list of words, given a table.  Assume the number of words can be quite large.  Also, can assume only need 1 match or theres only 1 match per word.  If a match is found, there is no need to replace or even check for the other substrings.

My current solution is brute force, taking O(nmk):

```
words = ['dfacatlgajd', 'sdfalafjump', 'adfasfhagl']

conversion = {'cat': 'dog',
              'car': 'zoom',
              'jump': 'over'}

new_words = []
for word in words:
    updated = False
    for k, v in conversion.items():
        if k in word:
            new = word.replace(k, v)
            updated = True
            new_words.append(new)
            break
    if not updated:
        new_words.append(word)

print(new_words)
```

Output:

```
['dfadoglgajd', 'sdfalafover', 'adfasfhagl']
```

Comment: You can use the `for .. else` construct instead of keeping a flag (`updated`) but otherwise your code is fine.

Comment: Looking for a more optimal solution. I have to iterate a word multiple times with this implementation

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with *`repl`* function.

Comment: @martineau That was my first thought as well, but in testing it out, it runs significantly slower than the original code.

Comment: Were you using a (single) regex pattern that matched any of the substrings?

Comment: @martineau I was, yes. The keys of `conversion` joined by `|`.

Comment: @martineau If you're curious, [here's my test code](https://gist.github.com/HalfWhitt/b9323e497dcaa9edb5691ccadaf11dbd). Perhaps I'm missing something obvious? The regex version took more than twice as long.

Comment: Your regex implementation and testing methodology look just fine, Am just very surprised that using `re` isn't significantly faster than your Python based brute-force code, much less the complete oppose of that, although on my system the speed difference wasn't quite as much — "only" 1.55 vs 2.36 secs.

Answer (score 2):

If the text has length n, the set of words to find have total length m, and there are k occurrences of these words in the text, all occurrences can be found in O(m+n+k) time using the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). If you perform replacements by writing out the new version of the string as you go, this only adds time proportional to its total length.

A less complicated but almost equally fast approach is to apply the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to find all occurrences of *same-length* words. You will need to rerun the algorithm (or interleave runs of it by maintaining multiple hashes of various lengths) to handle words with different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly an *answer*, but code blocks don't fit in comments. You could avoid a conditional and the flag variable by assigning `new_word` to `word` at the start of each loop, and then reassigning it when needed:

```
new_words = []
for word in words:
    new_word = word
    for k, v in conversion.items():
        if k in word:
            new_word = word.replace(k, v)
            break
    new_words.append(new_word)
```

It seems to run *slightly* faster, but that might just be measurement variance. (It's not any different in terms of asymptotic complexity, but conditional checks do take time.) I personally find it cleaner to read, too, but your mileage may vary.